# Force without acceleration?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, acceleration, string

Suppose we have a metal block tied to a rope at a certain height and below it is a magnet,after some time we bring another magnet ,the rope doesn't break but was there more force applied on the metal block (f = ma but here the metal didn't move)?[image]

Answer (score 2):

The force holding the metal block also increases. You should think about the superposition of forces. The correct way to write your equation is $$\sum\vec{F}_i=m\vec a$$ Since the net force is zero, it just means that the forces cancel each other.

Answer (score 1):

In the formula F=ma , F is the net force on the block.

The forces acting on the block are : (assuming it's made of a magnetic material.)
1. Gravitational force (downward direction )
2. Magnetic force       (       "                  "          )
3. Tension (upward direction by the string.)

If the tension equals the other forces , net force on the block is zero . Hence the block doesn't move.

If we keep on adding more magnets then at a point of time 
 the tension will not be enough to hold the block. Then the block will fall.

Answer (score 0):

The tensional force is self-adjusting upto certain limit. So, as soon as you introduce the second magnet, the force of tension is increased to balance the additional force. So the net force remains zero and the metal remains static. If, you bring a very strong magnet, the the force will exceed the tensile strength of the string and the string will break to give an acceleration downwards.